# How can I complete this program without a break statement?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, break

Saw the idea of making a cnect--4 game from this site, so I decided to try it out myself using some code from here and some stuff I scrambeled together myself, and cannot get this simple concept to work without the break after the count and prompting the user to input x or o depending on which player is going.
I do NOT want to use break as this is making something I want to do to the project later on impossible.
The code SHOULD prompt the user for what column they'd like to place their piece. And this all works if I used a break statement but I do not want to use them and will make the game more difficult to code with later on when I expand upon it.
How can I make this program work the way it does now WITHOUT the break statement? I've tried removing the break statement but that makes the column full after a single input.

```
def play_spot(column, box, count):
    column = column - 1

    for row in reversed(range(len(box))):
        if box[row][column] == '-' and count % 2 == 0:
            box[row][column] = 'x'
            count += 1
            break

        if box[row][column] == '-' and count % 2 != 0:
            box[row][column] = 'o'
            count += 1
            break

    return box, count


def print_box(box):
    for row in box:
        print(''.join(row), end="\n")
    print()


def main():
    num_rows = int(input("Enter number of rows (5 minimum) :: "))
    num_cols = int(input("enter number of columns (5 minimum) :: "))
    box = [['-'] * num_cols for _ in range(num_rows)]
    print_box(box)
    is_winner = False
    count = 0
    while not is_winner:
        spot = int(input("Enter what column to place piece in :: "))
        box, count = play_spot(spot, box, count)
        print_box(box)

main()
```

I'm assuming the checkmark on someones name means they got the right answer? So if you help, I guess I'll give you that check mark? :)
Note: The code at the present moment works but I can't use it the way I want to due to the breaks. If you want to see what I want it to  look like, simply debug the code.

Comment: Could you explain what it is about using `break` that causes problems elsewhere?

Comment: check `return` from function (which you can do in the mid of it) and `continue` in for loops.... together with `break` they pretty much cover everything you can do :)

Comment: @ScottHunter possibly other thins should happen after the condition and within the `for` loop... just guessing though :)

Comment: Changing your question to something completely different after comments and answers have been given results in poor quality of this. If there is something new you want to ask, the proper way is make a new post.

Comment: Sorry, questions, once posted, should not be materially changed, especially after receiving answers. If you have another question, create a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a copy of your `return` statement where you have each `break`, which technically addresses your question but doesn't really change the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative "loop" could be something like:

```
def play_spot(column, box, count):
    column = column - 1

    for row in reversed(row for row in box if row[column] == "-")
        row[column] = 'x' if count % 2 == 0 else 'o'
        return box, count + 1
    else:
        return box, count
```

Its not really a loop, you're taking the first candidate and using it, so you could instead do:

```
def play_spot(column, box, count):
    column = column - 1

    try:
        row = next(reversed(row for row in box if row[column] == "-"))
        row[column] = 'x' if count % 2 == 0 else 'o'
        return box, count + 1
    except StopIteration:
        return box, count
```

Have you considered what you want to do if there are no spots to play? (Here you just return `box` and `count` straight back)